# How to find the probability that the variable will be less than the value of the random variable?

Tags: probability

There is a random quantity $L$, which is evenly distributed from 0 to $l_{\max}$.

How to find the dependence of the probability that the variable $x$ (positive) will be less than the value of the random variable $L$?

Intuitively, this will be an exponential dependence from zero to $l_{\max}$.
But I cannot prove it to myself. Any thoughts in which direction to think?

Comment: $P(x<l)=1-\frac x {l_{max}}$ for $0 <x <l_{\max}$.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random quantity L has the following distribution functio:

$$
F_{L}(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & x<0\\
\frac{x}{l_{max}}, & 0\leq x<l_{max}\\
1, & x\geq t_{stay}
\end{cases}
$$

The distribution function has the meaning of the probability that the value of a random variable l will be less than an arbitrary number x.

$$
F_{L}(x)=P(l<x).
$$

$l < x$ event, forms a complete group with $l\geq x$ event. Then the probability of this event is found by the formula:

$$
P(x\leq l)=1-P(l<x).
$$

Then the required probability is found by the formula:

$$
p(x)=1-\begin{cases}
0, & x<0\\
\frac{x}{l_{max}}, & 0\leq x<l_{max}\\
1, & x\geq l_{max}
\end{cases}
$$